# Aggregate function of concave functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I have two functions $f,g$ form $[0,1]^n$ to $R_{\geq 0 }$ that are concave and monotone.

Given a point $x =(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in [0,1]^n$, I define $\operatorname{cube}(x) = [0,x_1]\times \ldots \times [0,x_n]$.

Consider the aggregate function $h:[0,1]^n \rightarrow  R_{\geq 0 }$ where:
$h(x) =\max_{y \in \operatorname{cube}(x)} f(y)+g(x-y)$, where the minus is coordinate-wise.

Is it true that $h$ is also always concave?

Comment: What do you mean by a monotone function if it is  function of several variables?

Comment: By monotone, I mean that for $x\geq y$ that are coordinate-wise greater, i.e., $x_1\geq y_1 ,\ldots, x_n \geq y_n$, then f$(x)\geq f(y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes (and the monotonicity and nonnegativity conditions are not needed for this conclusion).

Indeed, extend $f$ and $g$ to concave functions $F$ and $G$ on $\mathbb R^n$ by letting $F:=-\infty$ and $G:=-\infty$ outside $[0,1]^n$. Then for $x\in[0,1]^n$ we have
$$h(x)=-((-F)\,{\scriptsize \square}\,(-G))(x),$$
where ${\scriptsize \square}$ denotes the [infimal convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Infimal_convolution). Since the infimal convolution of convex functions is convex, we see that $h$ is concave. $\quad\Box$